# Error in comparing cron expression

Tags: unit-test, scheduled-apex, cron

I am getting this weird error while comparing Cron expressions but I am not sure what it is indicating.

> **System.AssertException:**  Assertion Failed: Expected: 0 0 12 1/1 12 ?
>   2022, Actual: 0 0 12 1/1 12 ? 2022

Comment: Bad unit test or extra space somewhere

Comment: Thanks, dude I figured it out. It was the extra space in starting off expression.

Comment: You shouldn't assert on the CRON string anyway... just remove this assertion entirely.

Answer (score 0):

When testing your scheduled jobs, asserting on the CRON string is going to far. You should just verify that the job got scheduled and leave it at that.

```
MySchedulable job = new MySchedulable();

Test.startTest();
    system.schedule('Job Name', cron, job);
Test.stopTest();

system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT count() FROM CronTrigger], 'The job should be scheduled');
```

Comment: **[Let's chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57467/discussion-on-answer-by-adrian-larson-error-in-comparing-cron-expression)**.